# How do I make Firefox 4.0.1 actually check if the site is working?

Tags: firefox

I'm having problems with my Internet connection which are related to a dieing ADSL modem. It works for a time and then it stops working until the modem is reset.

My problem is that sometimes sites will timeout in Firefox because of problems with modem and when I do manage to make it work, Firefox won't even try to connect to the site which timed out. This will last for some period of time after which it will attempt to connect to the site again. Is there any way to bypass the time limit?

Comment: Did you try refreshing the page while overwriting the cache? You can do this by pressing Ctrl+Shift+F5

Comment: @David Yes and it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Have you tried clearing your DNS cache with ipconfig /flushdns from an administration command line (assuming windows)

Comment: does Left-Shift+F5 still work as a forced reload?

Comment: @Jane T  Looks interesting. I'll try that and report back.

Comment: @Jane T  Finally I had the problem again and flushdns solved it. Post that as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try clearing your DNS cache with ipconfig /flushdns from an administration command line (assuming windows)

Answer (score 1):

I think Firefox automatically switches to Offline mode if it detects that no internet connection is available. In Firefox 4 you can untick `Work Offline` within the Firefox menu on top left button.

If no `Work Offline` menu item appears there you're actually in online mode. Somehow Mozilla decided that this item only appears to disable offline mode, but not to enable it.

You can also press the <kbd>Alt</kbd> button to make the menu appear and then check whether `Work Offline` is enabled within the `File` menu.

If in online mode you can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> to force reload (AFAIK the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key is not needed).

Also remember that a DSL modem usually takes up to a minute to re-connect to the DSL network and log in to your provider. So after switching on the modem/router it might take a while until you can reload the page.

Maybe it's a good idea to replace the modem if your connection drops are modem-related. In most cases older DSL routers suffer from drying capacitors. In most cases I've experienced the router Ethernet switches silently die. Often this can be diagnosed quite easily by connecting a PC to the Switch (most often 100Mbps) and issue a continuous ping to its IP. On Widows command prompt you can type:

```
ping -t <IP>
ping -t 192.168.1.1
```

You should see replies with less than 5ms on LAN connection typically. If you experience random timeouts then your router is likely to be broken. In some cases it helps to set Ethernet connection speed to 10Mbps/FullDuplex by manually changing the connection settings. But this usually just helps for a couple of weeks until the Router/Switch dies completely.

So bottom line is: It might be better to look for the cause of the problem of losing the connection instead of tweaking around in Firefox.

Comment: +1 for effort, but it's not the offline mode. When FF is in offline mode, trying to access any site which isn't in cache will provide the offline mode error. In my case I get server not found error and I can access other sites fine. Unfortunately, due to reasons too complicated to go into now, I can't do the obvious solution and replace the modem.